# Should I disable avahi-daemon?

Tags: networking, services, avahi

Every time I connect my computer to the network, I get a long list of network printers which I cannot use.

In this page: [Disable Cups automatic remote printer detection](http://brainextender.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/disable-cups-automatic-remote-printer.html) (see comments), someone suggested disabling avahi-daemon. I would do it if I knew what the consequences of this on my system.

Is it safe to disable this network service and what are the consequences of doing this?

Comment: Did the cups method that post is actually about not do the trick? A restart would be needed but it's potentially a much more surgical approach.

Comment: Browsing is set to Off in my default configuration file. As one user commented already, this method no longer works for recent CUPS versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, Ubuntu showed all printers in my job(about 50). I tried to disable dbus as suggested in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/996020/cannot-stop-network-printers-are-being-automatically-added), but i found out that when I tried to print something it took a considerable time to show any printers or preview. So I actually removed the avahi-daemon by

```
sudo apt remove avahi-daemon
```

It did the trick and at this point i haven't found any problems or faulty services/devices.